# Error while importing table through Sqoop in HDP 2.3.2 sandbox

Tags: hadoop, import, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import a 70+GB table in Hive on the HDP 2.3.2 sandbox, I have established a connection between the SQL Server and the sandbox, but, while trying to import the table using the following command:

```
sudo -u hdfs sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://XX.XX.XX.XX;database=XX;username=XX;password=XX" --table XX  --split-by ID --target-dir "/user/hdfs/Kunal/2" --hive-import -- --schema dbo
```

But its giving me the following error

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:165)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: The question title mentions an issue relating to primary keys, yet the error is about java version and jdbc compatibility issue. What am I missing?

Comment: the table has no primary key, i can see databases after i do sqoop list-databases; but while i a running an import query i am getting an runtime exception with sqljdbc4.jar

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: To use single mapper (-m 1), note single - symbol. But the whole 70GB will be read in sigle thread , you may face dealy in completing , might as well written into a single hdfs file .

Option 2: To use --split-by with sparse distributed , --split-by    Column of the table used to split work units. Ex. Employee_id in emp table will be unique and sparse distibuted .

Refer : http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html  latest sqoop user guide.

Comment: Well I have read the document and have edited the question. still facing issue, have mentioned the query and the error at the end of the question